# Fetch video duration using the new Vimeo Api

Tags: php, json, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a simple wordpress plugin which should fetch information from Vimeo. I was trying to fetch video duration metadata from vimeo using their "simple api" with the following code:

```
 function vimeo_duration ($id) {
 try {


  $ch = curl_init("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$id/json");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  $obj = json_decode($res, true);
  return $obj[0]['duration'];   

} catch (Exception $e) {
  # returning 0 if the Vimeo API fails for some reason.
  return '0';
 }
}
```

**Result:** Whitespace. It's not fetching anything and there's no "0" as well.

This link is the one we're using to fetch the information from: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/244509537/json , and it gives the following results when you load it in your browser:

[image]

(The end 'json' can be replaced with "/php" or"/xml" and it will give the result in the corresponding format.)

However I found out that **this api is no longer supported** and I'll have to use the **new Api** to fetch the duration data that I want. (perhaps that's why it's not fetching the data)

I've searched through StackOverflowa and other sources and I can't find a working example of this. I've also read through the vimeo documentation, however I can't implement it. I've created the **API** as they suggest, and now have the **Access Token**.

I've used this code which I've found in StackOverflow and modified it a little. However it doesn't return any values. **The results** are again Whitespace. It's not fetching anything and it's not returning "0" as well.

```
function vimeo_duration ($id) {
try {
$authorization = 'your_vimeo_api_authorization_token_goes_here';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/$id",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer {$authorization}",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
    ),
));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($res, true);           
    return $obj[0]['duration'];

} catch (Exception $e) {     
   # returning 0 if the Vimeo API fails for some reason.
   return "0";
}
}
```

Can someone help with this code? I see other people are interested in using the new API to fetch different kinds of information but there are not many working examples here, and plenty of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function vimeo_duration ($id) {
try {
$authorization = 'your_vimeo_api_authorization_token_goes_here';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/$id?fields=duration",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer {$authorization}",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
    ),
));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($res, true);
    return $obj['duration'];

} catch (Exception $e) {
   # returning 0 if the Vimeo API fails for some reason.
   return "0";
}
}
```

Changes I made:

- Changed your API fetch URL from `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/$id` to `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/$id?fields=duration`. This tells our API to **only** pull back `duration` for you. The result is faster responses since we aren't processing data you don't use, and also higher rate limits. See https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter for more information.
- `return $obj[0]['duration'];` is now `return $obj['duration'];`. Since you're querying a single video, the resultset is an associative array.

Running these changes with the following, I receive back `9`:

```
print_r([
    'duration' => vimeo_duration(245823639)
]);
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. There must be a problem somewhere else in my script. I'll find out what that is, and I'll make sure to mark you answer afterwards.